# Multi-target rapid prototyping using Microsoft technologies?

Tags: silverlight, sketchflow, rapid-prototyping, multi-targeting

I want rapid prototyping: Quickly define screens, links, buttons etc. I want to easily interact with sample data. I want to see things "moving".

An example would be a mail account: I would like to say that a message has a sender, date, subject and content, then say that a "message" screen displays a list of message headers, and clicking on a message header opens a "view message" screen where a "reply" button leads to a "create reply" screen.

You know - Gmail :)

There are two catches:

1. I want multi-platform targeting: At this stage I'm not yet sure which parts of the project would run on the web, on desktop clients, or maybe on tablets and smart devices (Ok, Ok: iPad/iPod/iPhone).
2. I know and like Microsoft technologies: C# (or VB), ASP, Visual Studio etc. So I wouldn't like to switch to Rubi, PHP etc.

I thought Sketchflow was the answer, but this is Silverlight which is not portable.

I believe this need is not mine alone, so probably a solution exists out there!

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is a mistake to assume that you will be able to generate target code directly from a Sketchflow prototype. In Practice our Sketchflow projects wind up being throw-away as they do not conform to our code patterns (Prism/MVVM etc). Very little is kept (aside from the brilliant design ideas of course:) ). Having said that I find Sketchflow to be brilliant for designing and presenting concepts *which generally do not have to be shown on the target platform*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you say, it's a difficult choice.
Either you stuck with MS Technologies and the answer is Sketchflow (then Blend) and Silverlight which make development very easy, but that are not "standard" : works well on Windows, MacOS and quite well in Linux with MoonLight. Silverlight should work well with Windows Phone 7 but won't work with Apple Iphone/Ipads.

Either you can do it in HTML5, which will be standard, compatible with the most recent browsers (forget about IE 7, Firefox 3 and co) but then the development will not be as easy.

I don't know your app's complexity but i would start doing silverlight + webservices and a Iphone/Ipad app later (using the same webservices via json).

For information, the silverlight penetration rate is 55-60%.

Comment: "the silverlight penetration rate" is meaningless, as it is very different between markets and sectors.   E.g UK MOD computers are very unlickly to have silverlight on most of them yet, but most sport watching households in the USA has silverlight